# Characterization of Freudenthal (end) compactification

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, geometric-group-theory

I had seen somewhere in the literature that the Freudenthal compactification of a locally compact, connected, locally connected, $\sigma$-compact, Hausdorff topological space $X$, is the maximal ideal space of the $C^*$-algebra of the bounded continuous functions $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the property that there is a compact subset $K\subseteq X$ such that that $f(X\setminus K)$ is a finite set. However, that paper seems to vanish into the thin air, and I don't remember the author's name of that paper. I will be grateful if someone could help me find that paper.

**Update:**
While continuous functions with the above property can be continuously extended to the  Freudenthal compactification, the converse is not true. For example, the Freudenthal compactification of $X=(0,1)$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$, take the identity function $\mathrm{id}:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$, then there is no compact subset $K\subseteq X$ such that that $(X\setminus K)$ is a finite set.

Comment: Try M. Henriksen, *An algebraic characterization of the Freudenthal compactification for a class of rimcompact spaces*, Top. **2**, (1977), 169–178. ([review](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=540604), [link](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/hmc_fac_pub/323/)).